# How stream fusion works in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, optimization, iteration

Can I write my own map function that is subject to stream fusion in Haskell?

Why recursive iteration over list isn't subject to fusion? That completely kills the nice expressiveness of Haskell pattern matching: `foo (x:xx) ...`!

Are Prelude loop functions fused?

Comment: `Prelude.map`, like many `Prelude` functions is subject to build/foldr fusion, not stream fusion. This is just as fast as stream fusion but covers a different range of cases;  in particular build/foldr fusion is not pathological with things like `concatMap` as stream fusion is.

Comment: To see how the fusion works, see that map is temporarily rewritten as here github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/libraries/base/GHC/Base.hs#L926 This permits removal of the list with the usual foldr/build rule here github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/libraries/base/GHC/Base.hs#L849 If the resulting internal foldr does not fuse with a build, everthing reverts to the standard recursive map as we see here github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/libraries/base/GHC/Base.hs#L927

Comment: FYI, the paper is extremely readable: http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.7401&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @Michael A bit off topic: What makes than text faster than string, when all loop operations are fused into one?

Comment: I'm not sure of all the factors, but `Text` gives a more compact, packed representation. In some cases of course, the fact that the whole text exists if the first Char exists will make it 'slower'. E.g. `T.readFile "/usr/share/dict/words >>= print . head` will be slower and use more memory.

Comment: But in general, a (fully developed) `String` of a million characters contains an immense arrangement of pointers each pointing to the next Char and a pointer and so on; the corresponding text is an array without pointers closely packing the information content of a `Char`. See the little calculation in http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/06/memory-footprints-of-some-common-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream fusion in Haskell is done using rewrite rules [(see the ghc documentation for more info)](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html). These are rules that you can specify in code using the `RULES` pragma.

The basic idea of rewirte rules is, that you specify a set of ways that code could be rewritten at compile time for example if you defined your own version of `map` as `map'`, you could do something like

```
{-# RULES 
   "map'/map'" forall f g xs. map' f (map' g xs) = map' (f . g) xs
  #-}
```

This introduces a rewrite rule called `map'/map'`.
What this rule would do, is that it would rewrite every mapping of a function `f` over a list that is in turn a `g` mapped over some `xs` into one single mapping of `(f . g)` over these xs.

There are a number of further sublteties to using rewrite rules. For example you can specify at what phase in the compiler a rule is applied, and the compiler doesn't have a way to check if those rules are correct.

The rewrite results are still typechecked, but if you did something semantically incorrect in a rewrite rule, that is purely on you.

Comment: Thanks, but thats only part of the answer. You missed the second question - Why ghc cannot infer fusion on its own?